# Android - Resuming application state - SL4A

Tags: android, sl4a

please dont harpoon me for a noob-ish question.

I am working on an android application using SL4A,  when my application starts it runs in the background while the script is being executed.  I'm not sure where to start but each time I click my icon,  it re-starts my application.  I have tried using different launchmodes with nothing different happening.  I'm thinking it has to do with the OnCreate code, and the setting of the notification.  I need help saving my application state and then resuming on either re-click of icon or click from notification bar.  I've tried everything had to turn here for help.  I am not a pro at android programming by any means. Thanks guys, be gentle ;)

```
         Public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInterpreterConfiguration = ((BaseApplication) getApplication())
            .getInterpreterConfiguration();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, final int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    String fileName = Script.getFileName(this);
    Interpreter interpreter = mInterpreterConfiguration
            .getInterpreterForScript(fileName);
    if (interpreter == null || !interpreter.isInstalled()) {
        mLatch.countDown();
        if (FeaturedInterpreters.isSupported(fileName)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_SCRIPT_PATH, fileName);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Log
                    .e(this, "Cannot find an interpreter for script "
                            + fileName);
        }
        stopSelf(startId);
        return;
    }

    // Copies script to internal memory.
    fileName = InterpreterUtils.getInterpreterRoot(this).getAbsolutePath()
            + "/" + fileName;
    File script = new File(fileName);
    // TODO(raaar): Check size here!
    if (!script.exists()) {
        script = FileUtils.copyFromStream(fileName, getResources()
                .openRawResource(Script.ID));
    }
    copyResourcesToLocal(); // Copy all resources

    if (Script.getFileExtension(this)
            .equals(HtmlInterpreter.HTML_EXTENSION)) {
        HtmlActivityTask htmlTask = ScriptLauncher.launchHtmlScript(script,
                this, intent, mInterpreterConfiguration);
        mFacadeManager = htmlTask.getRpcReceiverManager();
        mLatch.countDown();
        stopSelf(startId);
    } else {
        mProxy = new AndroidProxy(this, null, true);
        mProxy.startLocal();
        mLatch.countDown();
        ScriptLauncher.launchScript(script, mInterpreterConfiguration,
                mProxy, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProxy.shutdown();
                        stopSelf(startId);
                    }
                });
    }
}

RpcReceiverManager getRpcReceiverManager() throws InterruptedException {
    mLatch.await();
    if (mFacadeManager==null) { // Facade manage may not be available on startup.
    mFacadeManager = mProxy.getRpcReceiverManagerFactory()
    .getRpcReceiverManagers().get(0);
    }
    return mFacadeManager;
}

@Override
protected Notification createNotification() {
    Notification notification =
        new Notification(R.drawable.script_logo_48, this.getString(R.string.loading), System.currentTimeMillis());
    // This contentIntent is a noop.
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, this.getString(R.string.app_name), this.getString(R.string.loading), contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    return notification;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of different questions here. Firstly, a script doing some work in your app probably should not be initiated inside of an Activity. This is because you probably aren't looking to have your script's execution tied to the lifecycle of an Acitivty. I recommend checking out the Activity lifecycle @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

I recommend using a Service to control the work of the script. As the docs state

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

The service is also typically where you want to be controlling the showing and canceling of your notification. As far as launch modes of activities from the notification intent goes, this can get complicated, but typically you'll want to ensure that the launching of your Activity from within the notification doesn't cause duplicate activities to be created. Take a look @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html for some details on that.

Comment: @toyotajon93 yes, why wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

onRestart will trigger onStart so every time you restart the app, the script is triggered again. Check out http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/app/Activity.html for a handy Android lifecycle flow.

I wonder if this is something that would be better implemented as a service, with the activity just triggering the service?

Comment: I'm going to try and figure this out.  I'm not super familiar with the Android framework,  thats why I chose this route for my project. Thanks